# AirPrint for iPhone App

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiwebview, airprint

Been trying to get this printing but it doesn't show up in the printer simulator.

This is my code to get it printing:

```
-(void)printItem:(NSString*)path {       

//    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *dataFromPath = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"http://www.endnote.com/support/helpdocs/EN%208%20Scripted%20Demo.pdf"];
//    path = @"http://www.samplepdf.com/sample.pdf";
path = @"http://www.endnote.com/support/helpdocs/EN%208%20Scripted%20Demo.pdf";

UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
NSLog(@"Can we print? %@",printController);
//    NSLog(@"Secondly, Can we print? %@",[UIPrintInteractionController canPrintURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]]);
//    if(printController && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:dataFromPath]) {

    printController.delegate = self;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = [path lastPathComponent];
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    printController.printInfo = printInfo;
    printController.showsPageRange = YES;
    printController.printingItem = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) {
            NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
        }
    };

    [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

 //    }
}
```

The printer options modal pops up and allows me to choose which printer, range, copy and double sided. When I press the range, it knows that the url I'm trying to print out has 4 pages in it. I know this because when I try another url with 1 page, the page range shows 1 page.

Any ideas?

Thanks.